# is this a bug in dtwclust package using multivariate data?

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis

I'm using the `dtwclust` package to classify time-series data. I've played around with it extensively using univariate data and have figured out it's ins and outs. Using multivariate data is a bit less well documented but I was able to make it work using DTW and hierarchical clustering. When I try it using DTW and partitional clustering the plotting function returns a warning and the plot itself is pretty incomprehensible. This is the same with the example data they cite in the reference manual:

```
        # Multivariate series, provided as a list of matrices
mv <- CharTrajMV[1L:20L]
# Using GAK distance
mvc <- tsclust(mv, k = 4L, distance = "gak", seed = 390,
                args = tsclust_args(dist = list(sigma = 100)))
# Note how the variables of each series are appended one after the other in the plot
plot(mvc)

        Warning messages:
    1: In data.frame(dfm, do.call(rbind, dfm_tcc)) :
      row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
    2: In data.frame(dfcm, do.call(rbind, dfcm_tc)) :
      row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

[image]

It appears that there is fill being added under the lines, which isn't being added in the univariate case. Series are also no "appended one after the other" which I'm still unclear on what that exactly means.

Before I reported this as a bug on Github I was hoping someone with experience could explain what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: Is `CharTrajMV[1L:20L]` missing a comma?

Comment: I don't think so. It's a list of 20 matrices, so it's only a single dimension. The matrices themselves have three columns and variable lengths. My data has 4 columns, 200 cells in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just heard from the author and it is, in fact, a bug. An issue has been posted to GitHub and there should be a fix in the future.

https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/issues/18